# Какой фрэймворк выбрать, для написания чат бота на python? Почему?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot, flask

Всю жизнь делал ботов на **aiogram**. Хотелось бы узнать, в чем плюсы и минусы данного фрэймворка, если сравнивать с **telebot** и **flask**. Буду благодарен, если ответите на данный вопрос **по подробнее**. Хотел бы узнать у каждого *плюсы*, *минусы* и *ваше мнение*. Спасибо!

Comment: «ваше мнение» оффтопик на этом сайте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**aiogram**

*Плюсы:*

- мощный и гибкий фреймворк с множеством возможностей для создания
  чат-ботов. Предоставляет поддержку нескольких платформ (Telegram, Discord, Slack)
- обеспечивает поддержку асинхронных запросов, что может
  существенно ускорить производительность бота.

*Минусы:*

- Использование aiogram требует некоторого уровня знаний Python и
  асинхронного программирования.
- Разработка бота на aiogram может занять больше времени, чем на
  других фреймворках.

**Telebot**

*Плюсы:*

- Telebot - простой и понятный фреймворк, который подходит для
  начинающих. Он обеспечивает поддержку Telegram API и может
  использоваться для создания различных типов ботов.
- Telebot предоставляет хорошую документацию.

*Минусы:*

- Telebot не поддерживает асинхронные запросы.
- Некоторые возможности Telegram API могут быть недоступны.

**Flask**

*Плюсы:*

- Flask - легкий фреймворк.
- Flask позволяет создавать ботов с более сложной логикой.

*Минусы:*

- Flask может быть сложным для начинающих.
- Flask может быть неэффективен для ботов с высокой нагрузкой.